# How to typeset a variant of \lesseqgtr with a slanted "eq" (\lesseqslantgtr)?

Tags: symbols

I have managed to make something very similar to what I want via

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\lesseqslantgtr{\;\stackanchor[-1pt]{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}{\ensuremath{>}}\;}
```

but the vertical spacing is off (the symbol is too high).

---

I would like it to be vertically aligned so that its center (the center of the "slanted eq") is vertically aligned with the center of a normal `\lesseqgtr`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb,rotating}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\lesseqslantgtranchor{  %% MY SOLUTION
  \;\stackanchor[-1pt]{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}{\ensuremath{>}}\;}

\newcommand\lesseqslantgtrinset{%  %% BERNARD'S ANSWER
  \stackMath\mathbin{\stackinset{c}{-0.25ex}{c}{1.25ex}{<}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{$ \eqslantgtr $}}}%
}

\[
x \lesseqslantgtranchor y \quad x \lesseqgtr y \quad A \lesseqslantgtranchor B \quad A \lesseqgtr B
\]

\[
x \lesseqslantgtrinset y \quad x \lesseqgtr y \quad A \lesseqslantgtrinset B \quad A \lesseqgtr B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: comparison]

The first solution is too high, and the second solution ([Bernard's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581690/211141)) is too low.

Comment: If I put your definition in a minimal document, the output seems fine to me. Can you clarify what you're looking for? It could be helpful to add a complete (i.e., compilable) example showing what you currently get, and a sketch of what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's easier to use lower level tools: an alignment and `\vcenter`.

In the picture, the hairline shows the formula axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\lesseqslantgtr}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil$\mathsurround=0pt ##$\cr
      \leqslant\cr
      \noalign{\vskip-0.25ex}
      >\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$a$} % set the math fonts

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \vrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.05pt
         depth  \dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.05pt
         width 2cm
}%
$a\lesseqslantgtr b+\frac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine} %
\usepackage{amssymb, rotating}
\newcommand\lesseqslantgtr{%
\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{-0.25ex}{c}{1.25ex}{<}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{$ \eqslantgtr $}}}%
}

\begin{document}

 $ A \lesseqslantgtr B$ \quad $A\eqslantgtr B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: Here is the result  for this variant:

```
\newcommand\varlesseqslantgtr{%
\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{-0.25ex}{c}{1.25ex}{<}{\raisebox{-0.23\height}{$ \eqslantgtr $}}}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit too low, though. See updated question

Comment: @renyhp; I tried to (approximately) centre the symbol on the maths axis, by trial and error. The vertical placement is done through the first argument of  `\raisebox`. You may change the -0.5\height value to another one, e.g. -0.2\height and see if you prefer the position of the resulting symbol.

Comment: Why `\mathbin`?

Comment: @egreg: Sorry , I started from an old code and forgot to change that. I'll fix it instantly. Thank you for pointing it!